# Is it possible to enlist an Nhibernate session in the current transaction?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, transactions

Is it possible to enlist newly created Nhibernate session in the current transaction?

Explanation:

I have an active transaction and would like to create a session that uses this active transaction. I know that there's

```
factory.OpenSession(existingConnection);
```

but this method ignores the transaction that was started on this existing connection.

I am looking for something to this effect or a work around:

```
 factory.OpenSession(existingConnection).Enlist(existingConnection.Transaction);
```

Comment: `factory.OpenSession(existingConnection).BeginTransaction()` could do the trick. Just confirm that it uses the transaction already in effect